# JUnit assertEquals() is failing even though they appear to be equal

Tags: java, netbeans, junit

I am new to using JUnit so it's likely I'm missing something completely basic, however the following is the output I receive:

```
Testcase: testDateFromDayOfYear(p3.DateADTest): FAILED
expected: p3.DateAD<Saturday, 1 January, 2000> but was: p3.DateAD<Saturday, 1 January, 2000>
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected: p3.DateAD<Saturday, 1 January, 2000> but was: p3.DateAD<Saturday, 1 January, 2000>
    at p3.DateADTest.testDateFromDayOfYear(DateADTest.java:85)
```

I also compared the two objects:

```
System.out.println("*******************************************");
System.out.println(result.getClass());
System.out.println(expResult.getClass());
System.out.println("*******************************************");

*******************************************
class p3.DateAD
class p3.DateAD
*******************************************
```

Could someone please offer some advice?

**Complete code for test method:**

```
@Test
public void testDateFromDayOfYear() {
    System.out.println("dateFromDayOfYear");
    short dayOfYear = (short)1;
    short year = (short)2000;
    DateAD instance = new DateAD();
    DateAD expResult = new DateAD(dayOfYear, (short)1, year);
    DateAD result = instance.dateFromDayOfYear(dayOfYear, year);
    System.out.println("*******************************************");
    System.out.println(result.getClass());
    System.out.println(expResult.getClass());
    System.out.println("*******************************************");
    assertEquals(expResult, result);
}
```

**Equals Method:**

```
public boolean equals(Object inputDate) {
    if (this.year == inputDate.year && 
            this.dayOfYear == inputDate.dayOfYear) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your `equals` implementation?

Comment: `assertEquals` boils down to a simple call to `.equals()`. So change `assertEquals(expResult, result);` to `expResult.equals(result);` and debug it to understand why it is returning `false` (most likely, the method `equals()` on class `DateAD` is **not** overridden and should be).

Comment: So I have an equals method in my DateAD class that returns a boolean, and it works, however if I indicate it's an @Override method then I receive `method does not override or implement a method from a supertype`.  I've added my equals method to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assertEquals` will call `equals` which refers to the memory location of reference types. If you can override the `Equals` (and `getHashCode`) methods of `DateAD` you should do that.

Otherwise, perform an equals check on the hours, minutes, days, etc which make up the date (or time in milli/nanoseconds).

```
public boolean equals(Object o){
 if(o == null) { return false; }
 if(!(o instanceOf DateAD)) { return false; }
 DateAD date = (DateAD) o;

 return (this.year == date.year && this.dayOfYear == inputDate.dayOfYear);
}
```

Comment: This equals and hashcode stuff is way over my head, I got it working but I don't really know why.  Using JUnit is not a requirement for this project at all, I was just trying to get it to work.  He gave us the declaration for the equals method he wanted us to implement, so what I did is add a call to my equals method in the override of the equals method, which I believe is called "overloading" the method.  My project is hosted here: https://github.com/jensbodal/p3.

Comment: @akevit: your `equals` implementation is almost correct. You say you're having an issue with the `@Override` annotation? That's because the signature of `equals` is `public boollean equals(Object o)`, not `public boolean equals (DateAD o)`. Change it to use `Object` and use a cast in your code. I'll edit my post with an example.